# What can cause ExecutorService.invokeAll() to throw an InterruptedException?

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

The javadoc says `invokeAll(Collection<> callables)` throws

> InterruptedException - if interrupted while waiting, in which case unfinished tasks are cancelled

but there is no documentation on why the call could be interrupted. My program does so - but very rarely and I can not write a test that would cause it to happen.

I'm using the one parameter method without a timeout.

```
public class ParallelUtil<T> {

    public interface Task<T> {
        public void execute(T data) throws Exception;
    }

    public void execute(final Task<T> task, Collection<T> targets) {
        ExecutorService executor = null;
        try {
            executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
            execute(task, targets, executor);
        } finally {
            if (executor != null) {
                try {
                    executor.shutdown();
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }
    }

    private void execute(final Task<T> task, Collection<T> targets, ExecutorService executor) {
        List<Callable<Void>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        ...
        try {
            executor.invokeAll(tasks);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Here we get InterruptedException - for no reason?
            // With some of the tasks left undone!
        }
    }
}
```

InterruptedException is thrown (at least in some cases) from  `java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:40‌​0)`

There can be many of these `ParallelUtils` running at the same time (launched from different threads), but as you can see each call creates its own `ExecutorService`, so they should not mess each other.

(As a side question could I use a shared pool for all calls without the invokeAll calls messing each other?)

Comment: `} catch (Exception e) {}` You don't really swallow those, do you?

Comment: I'd decorate the Task with a facility to catch InterruptedExceptions to find out, which ones in particular are Interrupted. I suspect the interruption to happen in the execute code of one (or more) of the Tasks.

Comment: @Fildor No, I don't swallow them, I throw another exception there with some debug data. I'm not entirely sure what that decorator should look like -- the interrupt happens in internal logic of invokeAll()   (more precisely in  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:400) - I should add this bit of info to the question)

Comment: To return to this problem the cause was as follows: My threads were created by something running in a thread. The creating thread got interrupted (I knew that happens) -> interrupting the creating thread caused threads created by the interrupted thread to interrupt (without finishing their work).  The fix:  a flag in the creator of the creating thread that makes sure a running thread is not interrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There can be many of these ParallelUtils running at the same time (launched from different threads)

Apparently at least one of these threads is interrupted either directly via `Thread.interrupt()` or indirectly via e.g. `Future.cancel(true)` or `ExecutorService.shutdownNow()`.

Example to reproduce this interrupt:

```
class Sleep implements ParallelUtil.Task<Integer> {
  @Override
  public void execute(Integer data) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
  }
}

class InterruptInvokeAll {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    executorService.submit(
        () -> {
          ParallelUtil<Integer> parallelUtil = new ParallelUtil<>();
          parallelUtil.execute(new Sleep(), Arrays.asList(1));
        });

    executorService.shutdownNow(); // indirectly interrupts thread that calls executor.invokeAll
   }    
}
```

Comment: The threads that launch ParallelUtils are indeed interrupted (to wake them up from sleep when new work arrives) -- but I have assumed this only awakes them from sleep and has no effect if the thread is doing work. If they are doing work (which they are when they create a ParallelUtil), would an interrupt on the "parent" thread cause invokeAll() to interrupt?

Comment: @EskoPiirainen Not sure what do you mean by "parent" thread. If a thread that invoked `invokeAll()` (or any other _interruptible_ method, e.g. `Thread.sleep`) is interrupted, then the method call is aborted with an `InterruptedException` (and the thread's interrupted flag is cleared).

Comment: This little test https://bitbucket.org/snippets/epiirainen/ep6g58 shows to me that while thread is doing work it will be interrupted only after it starts sleeping. Output is: 0 Doing work
515 Now I will interrupt
5429 Stopped working
5429 Now I was interrupted from sleep

Comment: (I posted the above just seconds after your response..) Thank you, I think we are close to the problem now then. I'll write a test to confirm.

Comment: True enough. https://bitbucket.org/snippets/epiirainen/g9y9Xg -> 0 Doing work
0 working with a
15 working with c
15 working with b
109 Now I will interrupt -> java.lang.RuntimeException: 109 Now it happened ->  java.lang.InterruptedException
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:404) .   I have to make sure the "wake up call" does not interrupt the "parent"  if the parent is doing work.

Comment: This also explains why Jena RDF parser sometimes failed for no reason to InterruptedException...  Very inconvenient.

Answer (score 2):

> What can cause `ExecutorService.invokeAll()` to throw an `InterruptedException`?

See the javadoc for `shutdownNow()`:

> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. *For example, typical implementations will cancel via `Thread.interrupt()`, so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.*

Since `invokeAll` waits until all tasks in the have been completed, calling `shutdownNow()` from another thread is one way that an `invokeAll` call could be interrupted.

---

However, in the code *as you have shown it to us*, there are no calls to `shutdownNow()` and no obvious way for the executor service object to leak to another thread.

It is also possible that something in your code (or some other library code) is calling `Thread.interrupt`.  For example, one of the tasks might be doing this to itself.

Comment: In OP's code snippet the ExecutorService is local to the `public void execute(final Task<T> task, Collection<T> targets)` method. So I don't think this (shutdownNow being called) is very probable.

Comment: You are assuming that the OP's actual code mirrors this code.  If that is true, then you are right.  A call to `shutdownNow()` is impossible.  But ..... I'm pretty sure that this code has been simplified / sanitized.

Comment: Yes, my objection was based on that assumption. That's why I expressed my doubt in "probability" :) Your second point seems more likely to me. But only OP can verify that, I guess.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! There are no calls to shutdownNow() for these executors, but shutdownNow() is called twice in other parts of the system for entirely different executors. I assume executors are thread safe..

Comment: *"I assume executors are thread safe."* - You can always check.

Comment: (The reason I'm not answering directly is that it is generally speaking not possible to say if a class is totally thread safe.  Thread safety typically depends on how you use a class and its methods.  What you need to do is to examine how you are calling the methods, then look at the source code to see if the operations are thread safe the way you are using them.  The other point is that `ExecutorService` is an interface.  It is the implementations that matter .... for thread safety.)

Comment: This answer also contains the right cause (Thread.interrupt) but the other answer helped me to understand that it is interrupting the thread that created the ExecutorService getting interrupted that causes the invokeAll to interrupt prematurely. I'm not sure if this is desired functionality from the part of invokeAll. Not at least for my case.